# glove: proper way to create/apply It to an hand?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, workflow

I made a particular kind of glove for this hand, I archived this using a shrinkwarp and solidify modifier

[image: glove assets]
[image: glove hand white]

But this works well if the glove goes not on the "fingers" part of the hand!

[image: punch]
[image: error punch]

as a shrinkwarp modifier, It does what It is suppoused to, so It refers to the mesh Itself and not the form "finger" or "palm"

Am I building these gloves in the wrong way? suggestions?

It works sufficiently well only when the hand is open but I get these kinda bad points:

[image: errors to solve]

Attack the blend file, It's a little a mess and middle italian/english but e.thing is in the armature parent ^^

[image]

---

problem solved applying the modifiers in advice!

[image: problem solved]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool looking model.  I'd just apply the subsurf + shrinkwrap modifier and maybe delete the hand mesh that's underneath the glove.  Unless you plan on having the character unwrap the glove in a scene.

Comment: Applying the modifiers before moving the armature works perfectly! Problem solved!!! :D